# Jogar list em um array

Tags: c#

Eu criei estas duas variáveis para ser um `array`

```
public static string[] doc { get; set; }
public static string[] doc1 { get; set; }
```

E tenho estes dois itens, onde é uma `list`

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult, LoadOptions.None)
    .Descendants(ns + "ListaNfse")
    .Descendants(ns + "CompNfse")
    .Descendants(ns + "Nfse")
    .Elements(ns + "InfNfse")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        OutrasInformacoes = x.Element(ns + "OutrasInformacoes")?.Value,
        Numero = x.Element(ns + "Numero")?.Value,
        Codigo = x.Element(ns + "CodigoVerificacao")?.Value,
    }).ToList();

var xDoc1 = XDocument.Parse(soapResult, LoadOptions.None)
    .Descendants(ns + "ListaNfse")
    .Descendants(ns + "CompNfse")
    .Descendants(ns + "Nfse")
    .Elements(ns + "InfNfse")
    .Descendants(ns + "DeclaracaoPrestacaoServico")
    .Descendants(ns + "InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServico")
    .Descendants(ns + "Rps")
    .Elements(ns + "IdentificacaoRps")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        NumeroRPS = x.Element(ns + "Numero")?.Value,
    }).ToList();
```

Como posso jogar os valores destas listas no array ?

Tentei algo como:

```
doc = new string[] { xDoc.ToString() };
doc1 = new string[] { xDoc1.ToString() };
```

Porém não deu certo, como posso jogar, e depois utilizar esse array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se os resultados forem do tipo `string` pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
string[] doc = xDoc.Select(r => $"{r.OutrasInformacoes}|{r.Numero}|{r.Codigo}").ToArray();;
string[] doc1 = xDoc1.ToArray();
```

O *array* `doc` fica com as 3 propriedades concatenadas com um separador entre elas (**`|`**).

Depois, quando precisar utilizar os valores do *array* `doc` pode fazer o seguinte:

```
var docTmp = (from arr in array
              select new
              {
                  OutrasInformacoes = arr.Split('|')?[0],
                  Numero = arr.Split('|')?[1],
                  Codigo = arr.Split('|')?[2]
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Tentei desta forma, e ele me retornou o seguinte erro: Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "<anonymous type: string OutrasInformacoes, string Numero, string Codigo>[]" em "string[]"

Comment: O `xDoc` tem 3 propriedades, não é possível converter isso diretamente para um `Array`. Não pode juntar essa informação numa só `string`? Ou qual das propriedades é que deveria ir para o `Array`?

Comment: Eu preciso dos 3 tipos, como posso pegar esses valores ?

Comment: Resposta editada.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, obrigado pela resposta e pela explicação, deu pra entender. Obrigado.